# how to make "desktop example" with extjs 4.0 beta 3?

Tags: extjs

sorry if my english bad...
have you try extjs v4.0 beta 3 ?

in the "ext4beta3" folder that I downloaded before, there is desktop sample.
but, when I see the source code, this is what i got:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/ext-all.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/StartMenu.js"></script>
.....
<script type="text/javascript" src="sample.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../builds/ext-all-sandbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sandbox.js"></script>
```

why still need ext-base.js? and I cann't find it in the downloaded folder
i just can find ext-core.js, wich looks similar with ext-base..
but when i change it to ext-core.js it shows me error

maybe my big problem is i've been learn extjs 3.x since fews months ago...
and now sencha has issued "extjs v4 beta 3" when I have not proficient with version 3 ..

someone can show me the example how to make desktop sample from pure ext4?? (i mean all from downloaded folder)...
or just a helo word...

sorry if my english bad, i hope you got what i mean...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about what's in there currently, but I do know that as of beta 3 the desktop example is still very much "in progress" and not yet ready for primetime.  It will hopefully be done for the 4.0 final.

Comment: thanks for the information... i'll be waiting for final version

Comment: will final release use pure ext4 or just keep it with sandbox? i have a project like desktop sample.. and i want it use pure Ext 4.. can you give me advice what should i do... just keep waiting the final (in hope that "desktop sample" in the final release will use pure ext4) or start making my own desktop with ext4.. i know that changing ext3 code to ext4 is not easy